# How fix AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fa8b0814da0, XGBoosterGetStrFeatureInfo): symbol not found

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, xgbclassifier

I want to run xgb on my Mac (specifications). I followed this instructions:  https://towardsdatascience.com/install-xgboost-and-lightgbm-on-apple-m1-macs-cb75180a2dda.
The result is the problem with XGBClassifier
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxNBj.png)